# What/Which minor gods/spirits are associated with Dionysus?

Tags: greek, dionysus

I know of:

- [Gelos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelos_(mythology)) (divine personification of laughter)
- [Comus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comus) (god of festivities, revels, and late-night hookups)  -
- [Agathodaemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agathodaemon) (*[daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(classical_mythology))* of vinyards and grainfields).

Are there any others?

Comment: Maenads come to mind.

Comment: Can you point out where you got Gelos and Agathodaemon from?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer I just linked them and added some detail.

Comment: Agathodaemon, spirit of vineyards(grape baring vines)

Gelos- According to Philostratus the Elder, he was believed to enter the retinue of Dionysus alongside Comus

[Agatho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agathodaemon)
[Gelos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelos_(mythology))

Answer (score 6):

- the **[Nysiads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nysiads)**

These are they Nymphs of Nysa, who cared for the young Dionysus before his return to Greece. The god's [childhood at Nysa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysus#Infancy_at_Mount_Nysa) is an important part of his cycle, not least because it is a reflection of [Zeus' own infancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus#Infancy), hidden from Cronus on Mt. Ida and cared for by nymphs.

- the satyr **[Silenus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silenus)**

was said to be his tutor at Nysa.  Like [Chiron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiron), Silenus is contradiction in that the races of the two (Centaurs and Satyrs, respectively) are wild and savage, while these named teachers are renowned for their wisdom.  Silenus is a good representation of the dual nature of Dionysus/wine--wine requires cultivation and craft to make, but it intoxicates and over-consumption can lead to irrationality and wild behavior ([maenads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maenad)).  This outlet of pent up energy in the [Bacchic revels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacchanalia) was understood to be beneficial.

- the great goddess **[Cybele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybele)**

was said to have cured him of his madness, and taught him the mysteries. Cybele is often regarded as a goddess with a dual dark and light nature, and would have made a formidable (and prestigious) mentor.  Like Dionysus, she is associated with "wild music, wine, and a disorderly, ecstatic following."

Answer (score 2):

The [theoi.com article on Dionysus](http://www.theoi.com/Olympios/Dionysos.html) lists [Silenus](http://www.theoi.com/Georgikos/Seilenos.html), the [satyrs](http://www.theoi.com/Georgikos/Satyroi.html), and the [maenads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maenad) as the god's retinue.